# How to allow current password blank or new password blank in changepassword Login Control ASP.net

Tags: asp.net

I would like to set new password as blank when changing password using changepassword control.
To supprt this scenario I have removed required field validator and compare validators from the changepassword control, it still fires

```
 ChangePassword1_ChangePasswordError(object sender, EventArgs e) event.
```

I am using custom membership provider and so at first time of logon user may have his/her password as blank.In Login Control I have removed required field validator for the password field, which works well and authenticates the user. but the changepassord control does'nt.

I have tried calling

```
MembershipProvider.ChangePassword(ChangePassword1.UserName, ChangePassword1.CurrentPassword, ChangePassword1.NewPassword)
```

from `ChangePassword1_ChangingPassword` event. This works but all the validations will not take place.

Answer (score 0):

After reading the code from reflector tool, I found that ChangePassword Control calls

```
private void AttemptChangePassword()
{
    if ((user != null) && user.ChangePassword(this.CurrentPasswordInternal,newPasswordInternal, false))
        {...}
}
```

In the above method `user.ChangePassword()` returns false when old or new password are null or blank.
So to overcome this issue you can extend `MembershipUser` class and override `ChangePassword` method as below.

```
public override bool ChangePassword(string oldPassword, string newPassword)
{
    return true;
}
```

On doing this we can pass blank passwords in the password fields.